# Which SDK has SQL Client for Windows Mobile?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I have about 3 old Windows Mobile 5 projects that connect to our SQL Server database using the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

Recently, I had to upgrade my instance of SQL for my local machine to include Integration Services. It took several tries to install it, with all of them failing. Finally, I simply removed all of the SQL programs from this PC, and installed [SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff398089.aspx) with [Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx). (I would not wish that on anyone)

Now, it seems that my copy of Visual Studio 2008 Professional has lost the `System.Data.SqlClient` package.

Currently, I have the following SDKs installed:

- [Windows Mobile 5.0 SDK for Pocket PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42)
- [Windows Mobile 6 Professional and Standard Software Development Kits Refresh](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135)
- [Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Developer Tool Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389)

Still, **SQL Client** is not found in my list of references, so I can't just add it.

### What do I still need to do?

[image: Reference List]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's non-intuitive, but you need the SQL Compact bits.  Note the location of the binary below:

[image]

Comment: And, like magic - all my problems went away. I hated having to ask such a basic question, but none of the answers I found to this online anywhere addressed the issue. Windows Mobile is just too old, I guess.

Comment: Bah, it's a totally non-intuitive install requirement.  I actually didn't know the answer until I looked up the reference in a project.